# Spring Transactions to ensure consistency across 2 REST services?

Tags: java, spring, rest, transactions, persistence

I have 2 REST apis where I "persist" data, in a "transaction". I'm curious to hear suggestions on how to ensure that if the 2nd one has trouble the first one could be "rolled back".

I currently have a retry loop and if that fails I send a delete to the first call.

It works fine, I was just curious if it is possible to use spring transactions to handle this.

For that matter, are there other options?

Comment: I think you can get better answer if you post this question in http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ That site should have more discussion regarding this. (But I maybe wrong, but worth a try)

Comment: Are you calling the REST APIs or are you providing the APIs?

Answer (score 3):

It would be very interesting and useful if something like this was possible, but I don't think it could be possible since there is no standard API for commits/rollbacks with REST APIs as there is with the JDBC API. With Spring, you could never simply mark a method as `@Transactional` since Spring would have no idea how to "roll back" anything you did over a REST call without having to explicitly state it.